# Conditional Statistics in R (dplyr solution preferred)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("num1" = 1:3, "num2" = 4:6, "num3" = c(NA, 10, 12), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

```
  num1 num2 num3
    1    4   NA
    2    5   10
    3    6   12
```

Is there a way to generate a summary table using the mean for every column conditionally? To elaborate, if a column in the data frame contains a null value, then `na.exclude` that null and compute the mean: (10 + 12) /2 = 11. If a column does not have any null values, then just compute the mean: e.g. (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 = 2 for `num1` column.

Desired output:

```
  mean_num1   mean_num2   mean_num3
     2             5          11
```

Comment: What you want is the default mean function with parameter `na.rm = TRUE`. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/mean

Comment: for a dplyr solution, check the across function. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over all columns with an "apply" function, with the mean() function, with the "na.rm=TRUE" argument.

Something like

```
sapply(df, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

num1 num2 num3 
   2    5   11
```

Then you could rename the vector as you please:

```
names(mean_col)<-paste0('mean_', names(mean_col))

mean_num1 mean_num2 mean_num3 
        2         5        11
```

With dplyr:

```
df%>%summarize(across(everything(), mean, na.rm=TRUE, .names = "mean_{col}"))
```

**Edit**

Or the simplest of all, with `colMeans()`:

```
colMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)
```